# How do i access data from an array with json data in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, api, rest

Hi guys i have been working with an api and they return a response like this. I am really confused on here cause i have tried accessing it like any other json data but it's returning an attempt to read error

[
{
"service": 1,
"name": "Followers",
"type": "Default",
"category": "First Category",
"rate": "0.90",
"min": "50",
"max": "10000",
"refill": true,
"cancel": true
},
{
"service": 2,
"name": "Comments",
"type": "Custom Comments",
"category": "Second Category",
"rate": "8",
"min": "10",
"max": "1500",
"refill": false,
"cancel": true
}
]

this is my api request

$api_key = "myapikey";
$link = "httpsaddresshere";

```
$params = [
    'key' => $api_key,
    'action' => 'services'
];

$url = curl_init($link);
curl_setopt($url, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($url, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($url, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);

$exec = curl_exec($url);
$result = json_decode($exec);
```

echo $result->name;

Api is working fine i am seeing result when i use var_dump; but it returns an error trying to access the data

Comment: Because `$result` is in array of objects. Try `$result[0]->name`;

Answer (score 0):

This is because the JSON returned is an array of objects.
Thus, while passing it into `json_decode` you would get the array of objects:

Doing this: `print_r($result);` would produce an output like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [service] => 1
            [name] => Followers
            [type] => Default
            [category] => First Category
            [rate] => 0.90
            [min] => 50
            [max] => 10000
            [refill] => 1
            [cancel] => 1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [service] => 2
            [name] => Comments
            [type] => Custom Comments
            [category] => Second Category
            [rate] => 8
            [min] => 10
            [max] => 1500
            [refill] => 
            [cancel] => 1
        )

)
```

Thus to access it you should replace:

`$result->name` with `$result{0}->name`

Or better if:

```
$result = json_decode($exec, true);
```

Would convert it into an array, thus access it as:

```
$result[0]['name'];
```

Just iterate on the result and get the response:

```
foreach($result as $res){
   
   //if result is array
   echo $res['name'];

   //if result is object
   echo $res->name;

}
```

Comment: Oh wow this is great thank you. It worked however, since i am getting more than a single result how do i loop through this now.

Comment: use foreach($result as $key=>$val){ echo "$key: $val"}

Comment: Do not forget to upvote and accept if it helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$result = json_decode($exec, true)
```

and the can access the array values by their key name like

```
$result[0]['service']
//shall out put followers
```